# Entity Framework doesn't lazy load Complex Type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lazy-loading

I have a problem with Lazy Loading in Entity Framework. I have some members, who check in regulary, so the following (simplified) model:

```
public class Member
{
    public int memberId { get; set; }
    public string name{ get; set; }
}

class CheckIn
{
    public int checkInId { get; set; }
    public virtual Member member { get; set; }
    public DateTime timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

and in the context:

```
public DbSet<Member> leden { get; set; }
public DbSet<CheckIn> checkins { get; set; }
```

So i verified that in the database the member property is filled in (it contains the memberId).

however, when i try to get all checkins:

```
IQueryable<CheckIn> Checkins = db.checkins;
```

it gathers all checkins, but everywhere, the member property is null. 
I tried setting

```
db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled= true;
```

but that didn't help. Anyone with an idea why this doesn't work?

Comment: How you configure the maps?

Comment: How do you mean? what kind of mapping should i apply here, since it's a 1...1 membership?

Comment: If you use code-first, you have to map between you entity and database table by data annotation and fluent API, I guess you use fluent API?

Comment: I honestly didn't know i had to use the fluent API for that, i assumed it would "just work", because it also works if i use one-to-many relationships

Comment: [Fluent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx)

Comment: I added             
    modelBuilder.Entity<CheckIn>().HasRequired(t => t.member);
but that didn't help...

Comment: Does `db.checkins.Include(c => c.Member)` load the members?

Comment: Sadly not! and i have no clue what causes it...

Answer (score 0):

**Lazy Loading of Complex Types is Not Possible:**
Note that EF always initializes the property values of a [complex type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj680147.aspx) right away, when the entity instance that holds the [complex object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb738472(v=vs.100).aspx) is loaded. EF does not support lazy loading for complex types (same limitation also exists if you want to have lazy loading for scalar properties of an entity). This is inconvenient when we have to deal with potentially large values (for example, a property of type `byte[]` on the Address complex type which has been mapped to a [VARBINARY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/swbw1ewb(v=vs.80).aspx) column on Users table and holds an image of the location described by the Address.).

[Information Source](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-2-complex-types)

Comment: Pls take a look at this http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-4-table-splitting

Table splitting and lazy load complex types

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the `virtual` keyword for lazy loading. In your model:

```
class CheckIn {
    public virtual Member member { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: An explanation `why` would be nice, so he (and fellow readers) understand why this is necessary.

Comment: Ah, i wasn't clear in my question, i already did that, but that didn't seem to help, sadly...